# Display Success Message After jQuery Ajax `success:` and reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I want to display a Bootstrap alert message right after a successful Ajax call and page reload

```
success: function(res) {
     window.location.reload();
     $('#success').html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>Row Deleted Successfuly</div>');
},
```

Comment: you reload a page, so how it can do the rest of the code? First do a #success then reload a page after few seconds

Comment: Trueman. so is there any other way to show the message after the page reload? like sessions or local storage?

Comment: oh you want it that way, you may set a cookie, call it for example "showmessage" with value "1", then after reloading read the cookie value, if it's "1" then show a message and set it to "0" or delete the cookie

Comment: but the example below will be executed after success, so why bother the cookie way :)

Comment: can you show me the cookie way in code below? thank you. i want the message stay put and giving the user a chance to read it and close it

Comment: does the page need to be reloaded? you can display a message and reload a page, after the user close the message. This will be more lightweight approach, so you do not need to check the cookie every time the page loads

Comment: well this a good way too. and i had in mind to reload the page on alert close button and it could work. but since i use datatables and php i want the tables take the effects and then show the message. so what's the problem with cookies or session? are they not safe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231388/discussion-between-trueman-and-ramiel).

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function(res) {
//this will display your success message
$('#success').html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>Row Deleted Successfuly</div>');

//then
setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(); },5000); //reload a page after 5 seconds

},
```

Comment: going further ... you got 5 seconds to get use of those buttons you've add ;)

Comment: I need to refresh the page first and then show the message until the user clicks close button